# Vue / axios filter types of same type as single item

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, axios, nuxt.js

I have an app where I want to show a list of items. When you click on a single item, you're sent to it's "page", where its info is displayed.

These items have a type.

Beneath the single item info, I want to display all items with the same type, filtered from the list of all items. However I have no idea what to return in my `filterItems()`-method. Since the axios-calls are done with `asyncData()` I don't have access to `singleitem.type`, do I?

HTML:

```html
<template>
    <div>
        <reusable-component v-for="item in singleitem" :key="item.id" />

        <reusable-component v-for="item in filterItems(type)" :key="item.id" />
    </div>
</template>
```

JS:

```js
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            singleitem: [],
            allitems: []
        }
    },

    asyncData() {
        // Grab single item from ID supplied
        return axios.get(`https://url/to/GetItemById${params.id}`)
        .then((result) => {
            return { singleitem: result.data }
        })

        // Grab all items
        return axios.get('https://url/to/GetAllItems')
        .then((result) => {
            return { allitems: result.data }
        })
    },

    methods: {
        filterItems() {
            // Filter items from all items that has same type as the singleitem
            return allitems.filter(function(type) {
                // Help!
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a use case of computed properties [https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html]

May be something like this:

```
computed: {
  filterItems: function() {
    return this.allitems.filter(item => item.type != singleitem.type);
  }
}
```

So whenever the data changed. filterItems get (re)computed.

Comment: Well, I was using `methods` for two reasons. First is that the Vue docs says the opposite, that `computed` is cached, where as `methods` is run every time. And second is because `computed` tells me `this.allitems.filter` is not a function :)

But thanks for the input. I will report back once I get correct data from the backend